# Dividing v-card into 3 part with different percentages

Tags: vuetify.js

I've been trying to divide v-card into 3 part.

Item's image on left one, title and details on center of card.

And price must be right side of card

Furthermore, it should be same if item's detail too long or too short.

[image: First one (What i get), second one (what i want)]

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

                            <v-card ripple @click="menuItemClicked(item)" class="pa-0 ma-0">



                                <div class="d-flex flex-row pt-2 pb-2">

                                    <v-col cols="2">
                                        <v-avatar :size="menuPhotoSize">
                                            <v-img src="https://atlas-content-cdn.pixelsquid.com/stock-images/cardboard-box-2M7wzKF-600.jpg">
                                                <template v-slot:placeholder>
                                                    <v-row class="fill-height ma-0" align="center" justify="center">
                                                        <v-progress-circular indeterminate color="grey lighten-5">
                                                        </v-progress-circular>
                                                    </v-row>
                                                </template>

                                            </v-img>
                                        </v-avatar>
                                    </v-col>


                                    <div class="ma-0 pa-0 pl-2">
                                        <v-card-text>
                                            <v-row no-gutters>
                                                <v-col cols="12">
                                                    <h1 style="font-size: 1.25em" style="min-width: 100px; max-width: 100%;" class="pl-2 flex-grow-1 flex-shrink-0">
                                                        Item Name
                                                    </h1>
                                                </v-col>
                                                <v-col cols="10">
                                                    <p class="pl-2">
                                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                                                    </p>
                                                </v-col>

                                            </v-row>
                                        </v-card-text>

                                    </div>

                                    <v-col cols="2">

                                        <h4 class="pt-2" style="font-size: 1.00em">$ 10</h4>


                                    </v-col>
                                </div>
                            </v-card>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily accomplish this by applying vuetify grid system. You can any other small modifications you need like font size and styling.

```
<v-card ripple class="pa-0 ma-0" width="400">
      <v-row>
        <v-col cols="3" align-self="center">
          <v-avatar>
            <v-img src="https://atlas-content-cdn.pixelsquid.com/stock-images/cardboard-box-2M7wzKF-600.jpg">
              <template v-slot:placeholder>
                <v-row class="fill-height ma-0" align="center" justify="center">
                  <v-progress-circular indeterminate color="grey lighten-5"></v-progress-circular>
                </v-row>
              </template>
            </v-img>
          </v-avatar>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="6">
          <v-card-title class="justify-center">
            Item Name
          </v-card-title>
          <v-card-text>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
          </v-card-text>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="3" align-self="center">
          <h4 class="pt-2" style="font-size: 1.00em">$ 10</h4>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-card>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried to use grid system but I could not use it as I want. Your answer is really helped :)

Comment: No problem @developer.alp.  Try to master the grid system. It could replace lots of redundant and messy code, if you do it properly.